# Can you open a new activity in a junit test?

Tags: android, junit4

I have a simple question, but couldn't find an answer.
So I want to test my app with different inputs.

I could just change them manually in the code, before I start my junit-test. But I would like to know if its possible to just start an other little app/activity where I can choose some inputs from a list and these choices should be used for my real app-test then.

Would be really nice, if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Robotium ? http://code.google.com/p/robotium/
It looks like it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out later when I have more time. After some minutes of research I didn't find how to do what I asked for, but maybe it just needs some more time. Maybe I have to explain it a bit more: When I start my test there should open an activity (independent from real app) where I can choose some variables => after I chose my input and click on "ok" I want to use these settings/input for my test for the real app. Is that possible with robotium? I hope you understand what I mean, my english isn't the best but I think it should be understandable. As I said I'll check it later again.